# how to store distance and time to reach between two location in Sqlite Database when open Google Map from An App using Intent?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-sqlite

how to parse and store  distance and time to reach in SQlite Database in Android when open Google Map from using intent  showing route and distance Automatically by navigating between two points?.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can parse data directly from the Google Maps app. There are a couple of ways to go about this though. I would look at implementing some of the Google Maps API in your app to run before starting the intent. Or setup navigation in your app between the two points directly.

If you only want distances and travel times, then I would look at the [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start). If you want inbuilt directions have a look at the other maps API like the full Android Maps API.